# How do I determine if my injury is work-related? Next steps?

Tags: united-states, texas

I live and work in Texas. I have had increasing neck and back issues since starting my job, and I recently visited a doctor to try and diagnose the issues.

The doctor said that the injury is most likely caused by repetitive strain, and from what I gather the strain is related to movements I perform at work.

I feel like this is not considered a "work-related" injury because the injury did not happen at work, and I was not required to file an injury report with my employer.

What should my next steps be to protect myself if this injury puts me out of work, either in the short-term or long-term?

Comment: Consider the difference between workers compensation and social security disability insurance. An architect who develops neck problems at age 55 would look to disability rather than workers comp. Work-related? Yes. Specific to an employer? No.

Comment: Consult with an industrial hygienist. https://www.aiha.org/about-ih/Pages/Find-an-Industrial-Hygienist.aspx

Comment: @jqning I see your point, but what about in my situation? I am young (24) and paying student loans that I took to get my job. My symptoms started only after I took the job, within the past 10 months.